# Internet Explorer Change Event Firing too soon

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to fire a change event when a select tag is changed. I'm noticing that if selected="selected" is included in any of the options except the first option the event does not work correctly. It seems to fire too soon. For example, the jQuery code is:

```
 $('.test').change(function(){
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
 });
```

and the html code is:

```
 <select class="test">
     <option value="option1">option1</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="option2">option2</option>
 </select>
```

This code fires the change event as soon as the select field is clicked, not when it is changed. I can fix this by simply removing the selected="selected" from the option, or by putting it in the first option. But I need the lower options selected. Please help!!!

Comment: This is working correctly for me in IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/8BSSz/).  Which version of IE are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: It is in IE8 and earlier versions.

Comment: Matt, I checked out your code with my browser and it worked fine. I must have something else in my script somewhere causing ie to freak out. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Your welcome, and good luck.  If you do find the answer to your question, post back here with what the fix was to help others who may find themselves in your shoes.

Comment: I just found the fix. I was using jquery version 1.4. I just tried my code using 1.6.1 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I couldn't find any other solution than using setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0), so the change event could just finish. It solved my problem when I was trying to get checked elements.